# Function is not defined on callbackFinished (winwheel library)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

When I try to call a function with the callbackFinished property inside the animation of winwheel I get function is not defined while it's defined on the same class.

```js
import React from 'react'
import Winwheel from 'winwheel'
import TweenMax from 'gsap'

const Roulette = ({ width, height, canvasId}) => {
    let winWheel = null

    const wheelData = {}

    const animation = {
            'type': 'spinToStop',
            'duration': 5,
            'spins': 8,
            'easing': 'Power2.easeInOut',
            'callbackFinished': 'alertPrize()' //Error here, can't get alertPrize() function
    }

    wheelData['animation'] = animation
    
    function alertPrize()
    {
        createWheel()
        // Call getIndicatedSegment() function to return pointer to the segment pointed to on wheel.
        let winningSegment = winWheel.getIndicatedSegment();
        // Basic alert of the segment text which is the prize name.
        alert("You have won " + winningSegment.text + "!");
    }

    const startAnimation = () => {
        winWheel = null
        createWheel()
        winWheel.startAnimation()
    }

    const createWheel = () => {
        if (typeof window !== 'undefined' && winWheel == null) {
            winWheel = new Winwheel(wheelData)
        }
    }

    createWheel()

    return (
        <div>
            <canvas id={canvasId} width={width} height={height} className='z-0'>
                Canvas not supported
            </canvas>
            <button onClick={startAnimation} className='absolute w-full h-full top-0'></button>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Any way of getting the function on callbackFinished?

Answer (score 0):

You are passing the function name as a `string` instead you need to pass it as a `reference`, heres the fixed code.

```
const animation = {
    'type': 'spinToStop',
    'duration': 5,
    'spins': 8,
    'easing': 'Power2.easeInOut',
    'callbackFinished': alertPrize
}
```

Comment: It is supposed to be a string as in the documentation, if I try to pass the function itself it will for some reason be executed 2 times when loading the page, but not when the animation is finished.